# Why does my alert box not appear when I insert a number outside the range?

Tags: range, alert, box

Thought I was getting the hang of this obviously not. I can input a number outside the range and there is no alert box.

```
<body>
<form action="trial.php" method="post" name="trial" target="_top">
<input class ="score" id = "scorebox" type="number" value="0" size="5" maxlength="5" 
 oninput="scorecheck()"/>
</form>

<script>
function scorecheck(){  

var check = parseInt((document.getElementByClassName('score').value));

if ((check < -1) || (check > 21)) 
    alert("Please enter in range between 0 to 21");
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check your console you might see some errors there.

In particular you may see something like `getElementByClassName` is not a function.
Luckily `getElementsByClassName` (note the 's' after Element) is a function, and it returns an array of all the elements with that class. We can then fix your code by doing this

```
var check = parseInt((document.getElementsByClassName('score')[0].value));
```